# What kind of tactile switch is this?

Tags: switches, identification, surface-mount, button, electro-mechanical

I am trying to find some tactile switches similar (or even better, identical) to the ones shown.

They are two stage, multi-way configuration.

Depressing one click connects the common pin to pin 1, and depressing further (second click) connects the common pin to pin 2. Undepressed the common pin is not connected.

The body measures 8x8mm with a height of 4mm. The overall height is around 6mm, depressed is around 5.5mm. SMD mount with 6 pins, G444D printed on the side.

I have searched everywhere, but I have no idea what the correct name is for such a switch, and it seems 8x8mm isn’t a common size.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea such a thing existed.

Comment: Neither had I. We learn something new every day!

Comment: @DKNguyen really? Most digital cameras have had this since like the 00s

Comment: @PasserbyOh yeah, I guess they do.

Answer (score 11):

This is a familiar feature in DSLR shutter controls- partial press for focus and full press for shoot.

[Here](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/prod/e/html/tact/surfacemount/sksd/sksdpce010.html) is a lower profile switch from (major Japanese switch manufacturer) ALPS. They call it a "Double Action Type"

[image]

Chinese manufacturers probably use somewhat different terminology when translated to English. Eg. 'jog button' seems to have been applied to more buttons than the typical rocking switches.

In this case the function is two SPST N.O. switches with a common, one switch closes, then the other, as pressure is increased. There are also a couple frame pads for grounding.

Comment: Thanks for the info, with that I was able to find 3 or 4 different items from various manufacturers, but they are all much smaller, and not readily available. Are there any other search terms that may help?

Comment: Once you find the manufacturers go through their websites and look for similar products. It's possible it's no longer made, so you may not be successful in finding the exact part. Specific product searches are off-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior is called "double action" by many manufacturers.  A not uncommon feature.

The size and packaging and specifics of the connections will vary by manufacturer and model and thats a bit beyond the scope here.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Do you know the what the abbreviation for such a switch would be? Like 3pdt or something like that?

Comment: @MickrigeMcMahon the behavior tends to make a switch designation like that difficult to describe but they could be considered spst x2.

Comment: I've also seen these described as 3-position pushbuttons.  See Otto Controls https://www.otto-controls.com/p2-3-position-momentary-action-pushbutton